# Перевернутый фон в div

Tags: css, html

Собственно вопрос, какие могут быть причины перевернутого фона внутри элемента html. Картинка нормальная, но отображается вверх ногами.

```css
.menu{
 text-align: center;
}
 .place{
  height: 49.5vw;
  float: left;
  background: url('../img/Maldives.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  1background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #ffffff
 }
 .point{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 17vw;
  background-size: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <div class="place col-md-12">Мальдивы</div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="point" style="background-image: url('img/Maldives_palm.jpg')">День первый</div>
 <div class="point" style="background-image: url('img/Maldives_cafe.jpg')">День второй</div>
 <div class="point">День третий</div>
 <div class="point">День четвертый</div>
 <div class="point">День пятый</div>
 <div class="point">День шестой</div>
 <div class="point">День седьмой</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вопрос в рамках html и CSS никаких скриптов не подключено

Comment: Покажите Ваш код. Без него гадать придётся очень долго.

Comment: Какая картинка? Какой код?

Comment: Код выложил, просто не предполагал, что так много вариантов может быть

Comment: Использую Bootstrap, в примере не подключен

Comment: картинку можете тоже выложить, раз проблема в ней

Comment: У меня нормально отображается с этим кодом. Только нужно единицу убрать в начале `1background-repeat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без кода я вижу 2 варианта:

1. [EXIF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF) Orientation – ваш просмотрщик фотографий показывает картинку с учетом EXIF, а браузер нет. Либо наоборот.
2. [CSS transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) – у вас стоят стили, где явно указан разворот картинки.

Попробуйте удалить информацию `EXIF` с ориентацией снимка.

Comment: Нет css3 не использовал. Браузер напрямую отображает картинку как надо. А через фон переворачивает))

Comment: Абсолютно верно, проблема в EXIF. Не знаю сколько бы искал